# Radio button not checked after click

Tags: knockout.js

I'm trying bind a `click` event to a radio button using Knockout. However, when the radio button is clicked, it's not saved.

Right now, I'm just returning `true` from the event. I can see that the event is indeed called. If I try to `console.log($parent.SelectedCrossing())` the value is saved. Any ideas?

My markup:

```html
<div class="row">
    <!-- ko foreach: SelectedRoutes -->
    <div class="jumbotron text-center">
        <table class="table table-hover borderless" data-bind="visible: availableRoutes().length">
            <tbody>
                <!-- ko foreach: availableRoutes -->
                <tr>
                    <td>
                        <input type="radio" data-bind="attr: { value: ID() + bkt(), name: $parentContext.$index() + 'optionsRoute', disabled: !IsBookable }, checked: $parent.SelectedCrossing, click: function () { $parents[1].AvailableRouteChosen($parents[0]) }" />
                    </td>
                    <td>
                        <span data-bind="dateTime: TimeOfDeparture"></span>
                    </td>
                    <td>
                        <span data-bind="dateTime: TimeOfArrival"></span>
                    </td>
                </tr>
                <!-- /ko -->
            </tbody>
        </table>
    </div>
    <!-- /ko -->
</div>
```

The js:

```
self.AvailableRouteChosen = function (obj) {
    return true;
}
```

Comment: Can you get us a JSFiddle?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

your click handler isn't returning anything:

```
click: function () { $parents[1].AvailableRouteChosen($parents[0]) }
```

although your underlying function is (and is returning true, which you need to do to override the default click behavior). just return the result:

```
click: function () { return $parents[1].AvailableRouteChosen($parents[0]) }
```

Comment: Great! That did the trick. Don't think I've stumbled across that in the examples I've used...

Comment: Perfect, thank you very much for this answer.  For those wondering, this is documented here: http://knockoutjs.com/documentation/click-binding.html.  Excerpt: "However, if you do want to let the default click action proceed, just return true from your click handler function."